# Enumeration of the vertices in a quad-edge structure

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry

A quad-edge is a well-known data structure used to represent planar subdivisions or polyhedra. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad-edge

The procedure to enumerate the edges works by recursively visiting edges, and for every edge, the next edge starting from the same origin and the next edge after reversal. A flag is used to mark the edges already visited and avoid looping.

```
void Enumerate(unsigned short E)
{
    if (Flag[E])
    {
        // Already visited
        return;
    }

    // Process the edge
    ...
    Flag[E]= true;

    // Recurse
    Enumerate(ONext(E));
    Enumerate(ONext(Sym(E)));
}
```

I am now trying to create a procedure to enumerate all vertices. A simple way is by enumerating the edges, and for every edge output the origin point. That takes an extra flag, per vertex.

My question: is there a better procedure, requiring flags on the vertices only ?

---

**Update:**

I am quoting Guibas & Stolfi in their seminal paper on subdivisions: "A slight modification of those algorithms* can be used to enumerate the vertices of the subdivision, in the sense of visiting exactly one edge out of every vertex."

[*Edge enumeration.]

This confirms my belief, but remains mysterious to me.

Comment: While I don't see an approach without iteration (converted to recursion or not): What exactly would make a procedure (asymptotically?) better?

Comment: @greybeard: The enumeration of the edges is linear, thus asymptotically optimal, but the vertices are visited several times. Same question holds for the faces.

Comment: With polyhedra embeddable in 3d space, I expect the ratio of edges to vertices *very* small.

Comment: @greybeard: see my update.